# problems installing rubyracer / execjs gem for jekyll

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

Trying to install `gem rubyracer` and `gem execjs` for reasons I can't remember.

Probably because I'm trying to deploy a jekyll site which is having major issues displaying on server.

So, tried running `jekyll --server`

Get this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/jekyll-coffeescript-1.0.0/lib/jekyll-coffeescript.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/jekyll-2.1.0/lib/jekyll.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/jekyll-2.1.0/bin/jekyll:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

So, hence the installation attempt of `rubyracer` and `execjs`

This is what I get when I try to install them (message is identical for both):

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/gem:8:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/gem:8
```

Environment is linux server. Not my laptop.

**additional information**

`which jekyll` gets this: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/jekyll`

`echo $PATH` gets this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/coffee/bin
```

`ruby -v` gets this: `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]`

`which ruby` gets this: `usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

`jekyll --server` is deprecated, you can use `jekyll serve`.

I guess that it something wrong with your RVM. Try to remove it with `rvm implode` and install it again.